# Python Flask inconsistent response time

Tags: python, flask

I would like to know why my local app using Python Flask shows inconsistency response time. Here is my example:

route: /api/v1/test

response time:(based on Postman result)

90ms(first response)

400ms(second response)

90ms(third response)

400ms(fourth response)

...

It is always like that. Has anyone experienced this ?

Thank You

Comment: Can you mention how are you measuring this?

Comment: I got the number by using postman.

Comment: What WSGI server are you using? The Flask development server?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton yes, I am using flask development server directly. using: app.run()

Comment: The next thing you need to answer is what is your application actually doing for each request. Is it processing data, talking to a backend service etc.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton In my example, the endpoint handle Login activity.